# Timestamps of files in image created with rules_docker's container_image rule are all set to zero

Tags: docker, bazel

I'm building an docker image with a call like this:

```
load(
"@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl",
"container_image"
)

container_image(
name = "image",
base = "@nginx//image",
files = ["nginx.conf"],
symlinks = {
    "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": "/nginx.conf",
},
tars = [":build_tar"],
tags = ["catalog"],
```

)

As you can see, the image is supposed to contain the content of the tar archive available at target `:build_tar`, as well as the `nginx.conf` file.
The problem is that all the timestamps of the contents of produced image (both files taken from the tar archive as well as `nginx.conf` file) are set to zero (i.e. midnight Jan 1st 1970).

It looks like the `container_image` rule is not preserving timestamps. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add information about `:build_tar`? I suspect that's where the problem is coming from.

Comment: The tar provided by `:build_tar` has correct timestamps in it. Somehow, when its contents gets repackaged into the image, all timestamps are zeroed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `enable_mtime_preservation = True` param to `container_image` call fixes the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

A way to fix it would be to take the image you want to base your container off of, deploy it, then copy the files into it while it is running, and finally repack it for deployment.

I understand that is not ideal but from the searching I've done, that's how everyone recommends doing it.

I am just going to add that I do not completely understand what the image is for so I may be completely wrong on how to fix it.